# Linq query is not working using another query inside

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am new to linq and I want to use a query that display the supervisor name from employees table. The table structure is:

```
Users(
Id int, 
usrFirstName nvarchar(20),
usrLastName nvarchar(20),
usrSupervisor int
)
```

My linq query:

```
        User userData = (User)Session["user"];
        var db = new scaleDBEntities();
        return this.Json((from userObj in db.Users
                          where userObj.Id.Equals(from idObj in db.Users
                                                  where idObj.Id.Equals(userData.Id)
                                                  select idObj.usrSupervisor)
                          select new
                          {
                              supervisorId = userObj.Id,
                              supervisorfName = userObj.usrFirstName,
                              supervisorlName = userObj.usrLastName,                                  
                          })
                          , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );
```

As you can see, the current user ID is stored in a session variable and used in the query to locate the supervisor name.

Well, this query is not working... To be more specific, the issue is with the internal query because when I replaced the query with just a number to represent a random ID it works

```
        User userData = (User)Session["user"];
        var db = new scaleDBEntities();
        return this.Json((from userObj in db.Users
                          where userObj.Id.Equals(1)
                          select new
                          {
                              supervisorId = userObj.Id,
                              supervisorfName = userObj.usrFirstName,
                              supervisorlName = userObj.usrLastName,                                  
                          })
                          , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                        );
```

Comment: Are you sure that userData.Id contains (correct) data?

Comment: Yes, userData.Id has the correct data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I don't normally use query syntax so I have put my code down with the method syntax instead.
I have divided the process into little steps to make it easier to find the issue.
Can you try the code below and see if you get any errors?

```
User userData = (User)Session["user"];
var db = new scaleDBEntities();

// grab user object
var usr = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == userData.Id);
if(usr == null) throw new Exception("Can't find user!");

// grab supervisor object
var superid = usr.usrSupervisor;
var supervisor = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == superid);
if(supervisor == null) throw new Exception("Can't find supervisor");

return this.Json( new { supervisorId = supervisor.Id, 
                        supervisorfName = supervisor.usrFirstName, 
                        supervisorlName = supervisor.usrLastName,}
                  , JSonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

**Edit**

To grab the supervisor id as an integer using a query instead,

```
var superid = db.Users.Where(u => u.Id = userData.Id)
                      .Select(u => u.usrSupervisor)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: I like the way you structured the answer, but no results using this one. Again, I am very sure that userData.Id has data because I tried my code again but instead of a query inside a query, I put userData.Id and I had the results.

Comment: have you tried using the usrSupervisor value instead of userData.id? i.e. if the userSupervisor = 3 for user (with id of 1), is there actually a user with id 3 in this table?

Comment: Yes, if there is a supervisor 3, it means I have userID 3. My issue is with the part of the linq where I need to grab usrSupervisor... It doesn't work like that. So, now I will try to separate it in different query but do you know how I can convert the linq result into integer?

Comment: Check the code under the //grab supervisor object. Since we retrieve the user object above this code, it is then easy to extract the supervisorid. Check the edit for code to only select the supervisorid in the result.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes, this is what I wanted :) But I am confused why it did not work using one complex query though? But really thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `Users` has a FK to itself, you should have a navigation property (likely called `User`) to the supervisor.

```
User userData = (User)Session["user"];
    var db = new scaleDBEntities();
    return this.Json((from userObj in db.Users
                      where userObj.Id.Equals(userData.Id)
                      select new
                      {
                          supervisorId = userObj.User.Id,
                          supervisorfName = userObj.User.usrFirstName,
                          supervisorlName = userObj.User.usrLastName,                                  
                      })
                      , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                    );
```

Comment: Where I can find this property? Sorry I am new to this